# How to kill same instance of NSTimer

Tags: ios6, nstimer

I want to do something with my NSTimer when i exit my controller, so that i don't invalidate NSTimer in viewDidDisappear

```
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(stopWatch)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];

- (void)stopWatch
{
// Do something
NSLog(@"stopWatch");
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
// Do not invalidate NSTimer here;
}
```

After exit this controller, i come back this controller and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(stopWatch)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES] ;
}
```

So i have 2 NSTimer run in the same time

How can i invalidate my previous NSTimer when i make a new one?

Best regards

Comment: I don't understand; how can you have two timers when you `invalidate` the old one?

Comment: because after 0.5 second, my "stopWatch" function has been called

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Why do you want the timer active when the view has disappeared?  Why start a new timer at all if you already have one running?  Some indication of what the timer does would be helpful.

Comment: i want to update somethings when i left my controller

Comment: @trojanfoe: what's the best solution to do somethings for all controller in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear exactly what the issue is, but if you want a persistent timer, then I would simply not create a new one if an old one exists:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   if (self.timer == nil)
   {
       self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(stopWatch)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
   }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store reference to it and use:

```
if([timer isValid]){
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

Or for your purpose:

```
if(![timer isValid]){
    //create timer
}
```